# Бог - не Микешка

Tags: фразеология

Услышал пословицу (или поговорку?) "Бог - не Микешка". Честно говоря, раньше с ней никогда не сталкивался. В чем ее смысл? И еще интересно было бы узнать, кто такой этот Микешка? Как я понимаю, это производная от какого-то имени. А от какого и, главное, чьего?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала.

Там скорее всего не "Микешка", а "Микишка" - уменьшительное от Никифор.

Вариантов поговорки много:

*Бог не Микишка – видит на ком шишка* (разбирается, ~Бог шельму метит)
*Бог не Микишка, у него своя книжка* (не следует чьим-то наставлением, не одурачишь)
*Бог не Микишка, ему не поставишь кукишку* (Не уйдешь от ответственности)
(есть еще, но они представляются совсем уж надуманными)

Общее между ними то, что к Богу нельзя подходить с человеческими мерками, а скрытый смыл может быть разным: "Не обманывай", "От судьбы не уйдешь" и т.д.

Обилие вариантов с разным смыслом говорит о том, что именно Микишка добавлен сюда просто для рифмы.

Вариантов с Мик**е**шкой почти нет, только
*Бог не Микешка — долго терпит да больно бьет*
*Бог не Микешка, всю правду видит*
Но тут явно что-то не в рифму )))

А вообще имен "для рифмы" довольно много: 
*Бог не Тимошка (Антошка, Ерошка), понимает немножко* 
*Бог не Тимошка, у него своя ложка* 
*Бог не Никитка, повыломает лытки (т. е. накажет)*
*Бог не Федяшка, ума не баклажка*

Ну и прочая...

Есть еще уапоминание (у Даля), что в исходном варианте поговорка, возможно, звучит иначе: */"Бог не Макеша – чем-нибудь да потеша"**. Возможно здесь поминается "Мокошь" - славянская богиня судьбы и возмездия, этакий аналог греческой Немезиды. Но сомнительно: по смыслу непонятно, да и фонетика несколько странно переделана.

Comment: да не стоит изгаляться, вот ваш "даль" из первого же поиска:
Очевидно, В. Даль имел в виду более правильный вариант звучания русской пословицы: Бог не Макеша – чем-нибудь да потеша. И мы можем привести ещё одну аналогичную поговорку: Бог не Микишка – видит на ком шишка.
а вот ссылочка на Даля:  http://dic.academic.ru/contents.nsf/dahl_proverbs/?f=0JHQtdGA0LU=&t=0JHQvtCz0YM=&nt=428&p=6